# I broke python and pip

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, conda

I have not used python since installing on my Mac OS for a class in probably 2015 (read: beginner. I know nothing about configuring environment/dependency stuff). Recently, I decided to use python again for simple scripting. Scripts were executing but I was unable to import a numpy dependency. I received error messages about my numpy and did a bunch of pip uninstall/reinstall/upgrade/install-ignore numpy stuff. I kept getting the following message:

*ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['/Users/userName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.*

I decided to address my outdated python; I googled how to do this and ran brew install python as suggested [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/).

This did not solve the issue. I kept trying answers I found online that had worked for other people, including uninstalling and reinstalling and upgrading pip/pip3. This resulted in an effed up pip. Calling pip -V returns:

*from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    ImportError: No module named pip._internal.cli.main*

At this point I realized that my system was looking in this anaconda file for all things python (which I probably installed at some point as a student 5 years ago). Now my pip doesn't work, my python is supposedly v3 according to homebrew, but everything is looking for a highly outdated anaconda file.

I even attempted to update anaconda via their [instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/). I get this error:

*ImportError: No module named conda.cli*

What have I done are there steps I can take to fix these issues?

Comment: For any beginner who is confused and searching for a similar solution: I solved this by deleting all anaconda files found both in Applications and in /usr/bin. I then commented out the anaconda $PATH in bash_profile and changed to the filepath listed when I attempted the brew update. I ran source ~/.bash_profile to update, and then used pip3 to re-install all my dependencies. Finally, running python3 fileName.py worked (note I had to use pip3 and python3, not the pip and python commands I had previously used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeroth rule... make a backup.

First rule... do not delete anything supplied by Apple. That includes anything under:

- `/bin`
- `/usr/bin`
- `/Applications`
- `/Library`

Second rule... do delete anything from **homebrew** because you can simply reinstall it later. Find **homebrew** Python packages with:

```
brew search python
```

and look for things with ticks (checkmarks) and delete with:

```
brew rm XYZ
```

Third rule... delete anything installed by Anaconda because you can simply reinstall later.

Fourth rule... be aware of what your shell is actually running when you type a command. So, if you want to know which actual Python interpreter you are running when you type `python3` for example, run:

```
type python3
```

Fifth rule, look at your PATH with:

```
echo $PATH
```

If there are any directories for Anaconda, or `/opt` or any other junk, alter your PATH to remove them, log out and back in for changes to take effect.